# Best practice for using and/or logic in this scenario?

Tags: mysql

Afternoon, here is my problem:

A user can make multiple selections for a search, upon which we need to select from a single column in a table where we have matching user ids to the criteria (you'll see example query below). These items can be in an assortment of AND/OR. For example:

User ID can have items:

1 and 3, or 4

or:

1 and 3 and 4

The user will enter the logic they want to apply in their search so we don't know for sure what the criteria will be in the select (AND/OR). I need to find an efficient solution for running a query/process to return the results.

I have tried a php process to select all of the criteria and then based on the logic the user chooses (and/or) to sort through the results, but this is a massive performance overhead on some large tables. One search was still running after a day..

The following query works very effectively, and unless someone has any other ideas I may have to write some code to generate a sql statement like this below and then run the query to get the results. It gets complicated with the mix of AND's and OR's though. This query is simple in that the logic is all AND:

```
select distinct(va1.userid) FROM validation_abilities as VA1 
INNER JOIN validation_abilities as va2 ON va1.userid = va2.userid
INNER JOIN validation_abilities as va3 ON va1.userid = va3.userid
INNER JOIN validation_abilities as va4 ON va1.userid = va4.userid
INNER JOIN validation_abilities as va5 ON va1.userid = va5.userid
WHERE va1.ability_id = ‘179’
AND va2.ability_id = ‘178’
AND va3.ability_id = ‘289’
AND va4.ability_id = ‘287’
AND va5.ability_id = ‘328’
```

I just need to see if there is a more efficient design to this, what do you think?

Comment: Why not use SELECT DISTINCT (va1.userid) FROM validation_abilities WHERE ability_id = ‘179’ OR ability_id = ‘178’ OR ability_id = ‘289’ OR ability_id = ‘287’ OR ability_id = ‘328’;

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The issue is the User may select that the result must have all of them or some of them. The OR logic on its own doesn't get us there.

Comment: Hmm, Programmers have enough problems with ands and ors I have my doubts that users will do any better..